# React unique state for every component of same type

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I am creating simple React App with Posts and Comments (similar to how facebook posts works). One post can have multiple comments and there are multiple posts. I am using useState() fuction in CommentsList component:

```
export default function CommentsList(props) {
const [comments, setComments] = React.useState([]);

function handleNewComment(comment) {
    setComments([<Comment text={comment} />, ...comments ]);
}

return (
    <ul className="comments-list">
       <CommentInput onNewComment={handleNewComment} />
       {comments}
    </ul>
);
}
```

Post component:

```
export default function Post(props) {


return (
    <div className="post">
        //...
        <CommentsList />     
    </div>
);
}
```

The problem is whenever I create new Post, all written comments became part of newest post. I need solution where every post have unique comments list and when the list changes, react re-render comments. What is the right solution?

Answer (score 0):

Your state should be the comment *texts* alone, not components. Let React take care of creating the components in the returned JSX:

```
export default function CommentsList(props) {
    const [comments, setComments] = React.useState([]);

    function handleNewComment(comment) {
        setComments([comment, ...comments]);
    }

    return (
        <ul className= "comments-list" >
            <CommentInput onNewComment={ handleNewComment } />
            { comments.map(comment => <Comment text={ comment } />) }
        </ul>
    );
}
```

Similarly, wherever you're using `Post`, return a *new instance* of `Post` every time, eg with

```
return <Post />
```

rather than saving Post instances in the parent component's state. State should not contain React elements, especially when those React elements may have state of their own - it can lead to confusing behavior like you're experiencing.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it's not solution for my problem. Comments are still not unique per post.